# Call one function after another function having a async function in itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to call one function `a()` after another function `b()` when `b()` contains a async function `c()`?

```
A() {

}

B() {

    //do sometihng
    c(); //async function 
    //do something

}
```

I want to call `A()` if `B()` including `c()` is done executing. But I can not modify function B().

Comment: what is in `c()`?

Answer (score 3):

```
async function b(){
  await c();
}

function a(){}

(async function(){
  await b();
  a();
})()
```

make b await c, then you can await b and execute a. another way would be:

```
function b(){

  return c();
}

b().then(a);
```

Comment: note that `async` and `await` not supported in all browsers

Comment: no, not at all... lots of legacy browsers that don't support them

Comment: @charlieftl no , i based my use of *async* on the question, where the op is talking about *async functions* ...

Comment: but I can not modify anything inside b()...Its already defined.

Comment: @avinash then its impossible

Comment: @Avinash, then `b` is badly designed, and you are without hope.

Comment: @trincot what about with({b:_=>b().then(a)}){c)} ? !)

Comment: @Jonas, an object with a `b` property? I don't see (besides the syntax errors) where you want to go to with that.

Comment: @trincot yep, that is used for variable lookup... oh and theres just a ( missing :/

Answer (score 1):

the keyword `await`is what you're looking for.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await :
*If a Promise is passed to an await expression, it waits for the Promise's resolution and returns the resolved value.*

```js
async function c() {
   await b();
   a();
}
```