# How can I pause execution of function that queries API until API has finished updating from prior fetch call?

Tags: javascript, async-await, single-page-application, fetch-api, json-api

###### Background

I have an email-client (Single Page Application) containing various mailboxes, where the `emails` in each mailbox are represented by JSON objects.

Users can send, delete and archive emails by sending a `fetch` request to an API. For example, to *delete an email*, a fetch request is sent via `PUT` method, updating the deleted property for that email to `deleted=true`.

Similarly, to display a mailbox, the API is queried to request emails based on a specified property. For example, the inbox view displays all emails with `deleted=false` and `archived=false`.

---

###### Current Design Problem

To delete an email, first the JSON data for that email is requested from the API. The response is then passed to the `delete_email()` function, which executes a second API request to update the `deleted` property for the email to `true`.

At this point, I want the `load_email()` function to pause until the API has finished updating, so that when the inbox is loaded, it does not include the email that was just deleted.

As currently constructed, the `load_mailbox('inbox')` function sometimes executes before the `delete_email()` API query has completed. Therefore, when the inbox first loads after deleting an email, the inbox still displays the deleted email (which is only removed once the page is refreshed).

Call to `delete_email()` and `load_mailbox()` triggered by `click` event.

```
fetch(`/emails/${email_id}`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(email => {
  delete_email(email);
  load_mailbox('inbox')
  location.reload();
```

**`delete_email()`**

```
function delete_email(email) {
  // Move email to trash if not currently deleted.
  if (email.deleted === false) {
    fetch(`emails/${email.id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        deleted: true,
        archived: false
      })
    })
  }
```

---

**Edit:** When applying the answer provided by [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david), using `async`, I still get the same error I received when using the `.then()` structure. It seems to work properly for the `if` condition of the `delete_email()` function – moving emails from inbox to trash.

```
async function delete_email(email) {
  // Move email to trash if not currently deleted.
  if (email.deleted === false) {
    await fetch(`emails/${email.id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        deleted: true,
        archived: false
      })
    })
  }
```

But for the `else` clause, returning emails to the inbox from trash, where the only difference is: `deleted=false`, displays multiple duplicates of each email in the inbox when the inbox is first loaded. It correctly updates once the page is refreshed.

```
  // If email is in trash, remove back to inbox.
    else {
      await fetch(`emails/${email.id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          deleted: false,
          archived: false
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

This uses the `async` version from David's answer:

```
async function get_email() {
  const response = await fetch(`/emails/${email_id}`);
  const email = await response.json();
  return email
}
get_email().then(async (email) => {
  await delete_email(email);
  load_mailbox('inbox');
})
```

---

**Related SO Posts:** Similar questions have been asked many times, but I have not been able to adapt them to my situation.

Using `setTimeout()`: [Wait 5 sec. before executing next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line)

Using `async` "caller": [Waiting for fetch to execute before next instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775517/waiting-for-the-fetch-to-complete-and-then-execute-the-next-instruction)

Calling multiple `async` functions: [Call one async after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421041/call-one-function-after-another-function-having-a-async-function-in-itself)

Function called after `fetch`: [Function returns before fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750976/function-returns-before-fetch-request-completes)

Using anonymous `.then()`: [Calling method after fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430522/calling-a-method-after-fetch-has-been-executed)

Comment: Use a promise feels like the right thing to do.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: After re-phrasing my question for clarity, would you say that is still the case?

Comment: @DAK: *"displays multiple duplicates of each email in the inbox when the inbox is first loaded"* - How have you confirmed that this is specifically an async timing issue for the code shown?  That is... If you place debugging breakpoints at the start of each operation and visibly confirm that the previous operation has completed before allowing the next one to begin, does the described problem still occur?  Is `load_mailbox('inbox')` simply writing duplicate entries to the UI in this case?

Answer (score 2):

First, make `delete_email` an `async` function.  This allows it to be awaitable:

```
async function delete_email(email) {
  // Move email to trash if not currently deleted.
  if (email.deleted === false) {
    await fetch(`emails/${email.id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        deleted: true,
        archived: false
      })
    })
  }
}
```

(You *could* also not use `async` and instead return the resulting `Promise` from `fetch`, but you'd also need to ensure that you return a `Promise` when that `if` condition isn't met, as you'll want this function to *always* return a `Promise`.)

Note how it internally uses `await` on the `fetch` operation.  The main difference now is that `delete_email` returns a `Promise`.  Which you can `await`:

```
.then(async (email) => {
   await delete_email(email);
   load_mailbox('inbox');
})
```

Or, continuing with the use of `.then()` structures:

```
.then(email => {
   return delete_email(email);
})
.then(() => {
   load_mailbox('inbox');
})
```

Basically, from the lengthy question it seems that you're drastically overthinking it.  Any asynchronous operation you create should return a `Promise`.  That `Promise` can be awaited with `await` (in an `async` function) or followed up with `.then()` (in a non-`async` function).

Comment: "Any asynchronous operation you create should return a Promise" exactly

Comment: @DAK: You'd use `.then()` on any `Promise` (generally returned from a function call) which you want to follow-up with some operation, but where you can't use the cleaner `await` syntax (because you're not in an `async` function).  Note that if the callback you pass to `.then()` *also* returns a `Promise` then you can chain additional `.then()` calls after it.

Comment: @DAK: It sounds like you're still overthinking it.  If you want to call `delete_mail()`, which internally performs an asynchronous operation, and then *after* that operation you want to call `load_mailbox()`, then (1) `delete_mail()` needs to return a `Promise` and (2) you'd either `await` that resulting `Promise` *or* follow it up with a `.then()` callback.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: @DAK: If `delete_email()` is `async` (as suggested above) then it always returns a `Promise`.  That `Promise` doesn't need to resolve to a value when it's awaited, but it can still be awaited.

Comment: @DAK: *"the way I had it originally isn't async"* - Which is why I suggest making it `async`.  Otherwise it wouldn't be awaitable, and your goal is to await it.  *"because delete_email() is not returning a Promise"* - If it's `async` then it returns a `Promise`.  `async` functions always return a `Promise`.  *"it didn't seem like that would be my solution"* - Don't just look at code and guess whether or not you think it would work, actually test and debug it and observe the behaviors.

Comment: @David: I updated the question, I hope I have made it clearer. Apologies, my initial post clearly was convoluted. Hopefully this makes it clearer and can make it easier to debug.